# Find the best combination of inputs that result in the optimal output for an ANN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, optimization, neural-network

I am working on a project that involves 10 inputs (X1, X2,..., X10) and predicts 3 outputs (Y1, Y2, Y3). I am using the Keras package in Python with the backend of Tensorflow. I have built an ANN, trained, and shown decent predictions.

```
    def build_model()
        input_layer = Input(shape=(len(train .columns),))
        first = Dense(units='1024', activation='relu')(input_layer)      
        second = Dense(units='512', activation='relu')(first)
        third = Dense(units='512', activation='relu')(second)
    
        # first output will be fed from the third dense
        y1_output = Dense(units='1', name='y1_output')(third)
        fourth = Dense(units='256', activation='relu')(third)
    
        # second output will be fed from the fourth dense
        y2_output = Dense(units='1', name='y2_output')(fourth)
        fifth = Dense(units='64', activation='relu')(fourth)
    
        # third output will be fed from the fifth dense
        y3_output = Dense(units='1', name='y3_output')(fifth)
    
       # Define the model with the input layer and a list of output layers
       model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[y1_output, y2_output, y3_output])

       return model

model = build_model()

print(model.summary())

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'y1_output': 'mse', 
                    'y2_output': 'mse', 
                    'y3_output': 'mse'},
              metrics={'y1_output': tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(),
                       'y2_output': tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(),
                       'y3_output': tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()})
```

How can a determine the values of the 10 inputs that produce the optimal outputs (Y1, Y2, Y3)? I am not sure if a genetic algorithm can help with this, and if so, I do not know how to implement it. Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Another option is [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) if you don't want a long computation time.